# AD Groups and permisions in Azure

Tags: azure

We are managing Azure Security with AD groups. Giving permisions to Resource Groups, Subscription and Resources.

I want to know if there exist any way to know all AD groups and their following permisions in Azure

Is this possible?

Comment: hi @exitista, did you manage to get something else on this accept for Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this pretty easily using the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) Using the API, you can easily query your AD for users, groups, etc.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Im not finding the way to do it by Microsoft Graph. How can I query what Im needing?

Comment: Here try this library,  with examples   https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/README.md

Comment: I can help further if needed.  But if this was helpful  consider marking as answer